# Java string.replaceAll issue

Tags: java, string

Consider the following code

```
 String unformattedXml ="<root>  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=";        

 unformattedXml = unformattedXml.replaceAll("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>","");

 System.out.println(unformattedXml);
```

Output is :

```
<root>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=
```

As you must have already understood, i want to remove the xml tag from the string, but somehow the `replaceAll` function is not helping me.

Any suggestions??

Thanks!

Comment: Try escaping your ?'s.

Comment: Before asking why a function does not do what you want it to do, please read the documentation to find out what it is actually supposed to do.

Comment: @ njzk2 and Natha Huges - Please dont waste time here if you dont want to answer question. I was just asking help and not begging you guys.For asking simple questions to downvote. So i have asked complicated questions which you 'self assumed' masters couldn't answer. So i should downvote you guys for the same ? why this hippocracy ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. The latter parses the input string as a regular expression causing characters like `?` to be treated as regex metacharacters:

```
unformattedXml = unformattedXml.replace(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "");
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But i have more than one xml tags in my file and i want to get rid of all of them. Will this help then?

Comment: @FaizAli Yes `replace` does replace all occurrences (even though it's called just `replace`).

Answer (score 1):

[String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes a regular expression as the first argument - try using [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace() instead of replaceAll()

```
String unformattedXml ="<root>  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=";
unformattedXml = unformattedXml.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>","");
System.out.println(unformattedXml);
```